# QGIS 2.14.2 Rotating map quick map service

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps, qgis-2.14, quickmapservices

I am currently using an Esri basemap. 
Standard built in functionality of QGIS 2.14.2 allows for the rotation of vectors, rasters etc. When I use rotate, all the vectors I added personally rotate just fine. 
However, rotation completely screws up the view of my basemap (esri topo. however the same holds for any other map I loaded in via the "Quick map service"). Whenever I rotate, QGIS does something to the basemap, tranforming the entire look of the map.

How can I rotate my basemap with it changing completely?

p.s. even if I try in map composer, the same thing happens.

----------UPDATE----------

Here are some pictures to help clarify to issue...

[image: Normal View. NO Rotation]
[image: Rotated view. Rotated 35 degrees. View is co]

The funny thing is, that the shape files, do rotate correctly. 
But the underlying basemap, gets completely warped. How to prevent this

Answer (score 2):

A work around in composer seems to be to rotate the frame [image: frame rotated]and not the content[image: content rotated]. As described in this post: 
[Blank Base Map when exporting from Print Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232591/blank-base-map-when-exporting-from-print-composer/232981#232981)