# Blank Base Map when exporting from Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, quickmapservices

When exporting from composer in QGIS to either an image or PDF the map does not print. I get a white page with only the shapefiles showing up.

This happens when the map is rotated 90 degrees. This only happens with maps from **QuickMapServices** plugin. If I load a raster image there are no issues.

Wondering if there is a way to get the QuickMapServices maps to show up when rotated 90 degrees?

This is what the map looks like in composer:
[image]

And this is what I get when I print the map
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider this situation as an example:

[image]

I'm quite sure you tried to set the rotation from the `Main properties`:

[image]

If I set `90` for the `Map rotation` field, I'm able to reproduce a situation similar to your issue, obtaining a partial or total blank map (it should depend on the extent of the map):

[image]

Instead, if I leave `0` as value for that field and I set `90` for the `Rotation` field:

[image]

I obtain this result:

[image]

As you can see, the map was correctly rotated. I voluntarily left a light green space around the map to let you see the difference between the two fields where you specify the rotation:

- if you set it from the `Main properties` tab, you don't apply any rotation to the map;
- if you set it from the `Rotation` tab, you apply the right rotation (and probably you need to edit the position and size of the map for leaving it with a landscape orientation).

Answer (score 1):

[This might help.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html) Its hard to address without much context but maybe the scale dependent visibility was set somewhere along the line.

Comment: I just checked and nothing was set for the scale dependent visibility